# How do I execute a Java app I built with Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I created a Maven project following the quickstart template as described in the Maven doc site. I can build it. However I'm confused: I can't find any instructions for executing an application built with Maven. I did find the suggestion I type `java -cp target/Mus-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.App` or something similar, but this fails when I added an external dependency to my Maven project.

Surely there must be some kind of Maven command for executing an App.

Comment: You have two options.  You can either include the external JARs on the command line in your call to `java`, _or_ you can tell Maven to generate an executable JAR, which will bundle all external dependencies inside of it.  Just poke around on Stack Overflow; this topic has already been well covered.

Comment: There's also `mvn exec:java`.

Comment: `mvn exec:java` gives an error about missing `mainClass` parameter. It's hard to find any examples of this online that are simple enough to copy immediately. If you can point me to a Maven tutorial that would not put me into a place in which `mainClass` is missing, I'm all ears.

Comment: @Tim, do you mean include jars on the command line such as the example I gave in the text? This fails when I write code that uses the guava jar, even when I include it explicitly in the list: the class loader can't find any guava classes. Thanks for tip re "external JAR" -- finally a search term that brings me to something useful.